# Android Testing - Signal Quality

Tags: android, android-testing, android-networking, android-internet

I want to test how my app functions with api calls in different levels of network strength. Is there anyway to control or limit the network strength on an android device? I want to test my app during minimal cellular signal, 3g signal, 4g signal, and wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an emulator on Android Studio you can select the speed of the network between those speeds :
Full
HSDPA
UMTS
EDGE
GPRS
HSCSD
GSM

You can also change it at runtime :
`emulator -netspeed gsm`

More infos here :
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: Thank you andros, that was very helpful